# running vscode as non root in RHEL8

Tags: visual-studio-code

i know it is not good to run **VSCODE** as root in **REDHAT** 8 .
When i run the following command in RHEL 8.0

**I get the response below:-**

> **cannot open display: :1**
>
> [kthulsidoss@redhat20201 ~]$ code . --user-data-dir='.' --verbose No
>   protocol specified (code:99480): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:45:01.222: cannot
>   open display: :1

Comment: are you trying to open VSCode over SSH with X11 Forwarding?

Comment: @tHeSiD i did install vscode as root ...it that the reason vscode does not open for a non root user. So what can be suggested here install firstly as a non root user (this user must be in sudoers file)